# Quickest way to exclude variables with zero variance in R

Tags: r, k-means

I am working with a very huge .csv dataset for an evaluation and yet I have got this error to resolve.

```
Warning in preProcess.default(data, method = c("center", "scale")) :
  These variables have zero variances: num_outbound_cmds, is_host_login
Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

What is the quickest way to exclude variables in my dataset `whose variance is zero (0)`?

Answer (score 8):

The R package `caret` has a function `nearZeroVar` that does a pretty good job of identifying columns in a matrix or data frame that have zero or near zero variance. It returns the indices as a vector, which you can use to remove those columns.

```
> df <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=sample(1:5), c=rep(1,5))
> df
  a b c
1 1 4 1
2 2 2 1
3 3 1 1
4 4 5 1
5 5 3 1
> nearZeroVar(df)
[1] 3
> df[,-nearZeroVar(df)]
  a b
1 1 4
2 2 2
3 3 1
4 4 5
5 5 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Using @Dthal's example, a `base R` option would be using `Filter`

```
Filter(var, df)
#  a b
#1 1 4
#2 2 2
#3 3 1
#4 4 5
#5 5 3
```

The above works by converting the variance that are 0 to FALSE and all other values to TRUE, and `Filter` only those columns that return TRUE.

---

If there are `NA`s (not using any external packages)

```
Filter(\(x) var(x, na.rm = TRUE), df)
  a  c
1 1  1
2 2  2
3 3 NA
4 4  3
5 5  4
```

Comment: This as it stands would not take into account missing values and also kick out any columns with missing values.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is

- not to call any extra packages into account, and
- you rely on `tidyverse`, and
- you'd like to take NA values into account, you can do something like

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(
  a = seq(5), 
  b = c(NA, rep(1, 4)), 
  c = c(1, 2, NA, 3, 4),
  d = rep(1, 5)
)
df
#   a  b  c d
# 1 1 NA  1 1
# 2 2  1  2 1
# 3 3  1 NA 1
# 4 4  1  3 1
# 5 5  1  4 1

Filter(
  function(x) case_when(
    all(is.na(x)) ~ FALSE,
    !all(is.na(x)) & var(x, na.rm = TRUE) == 0 ~ FALSE,
    TRUE ~ TRUE
  ), 
  df
)
#   a  c
# 1 1  1
# 2 2  2
# 3 3 NA
# 4 4  3
# 5 5  4
```

This would only calculate variance after removing the `NA`.

If you'd like to keep column `b` too, i.e., consider `NA` as part of variation as well, you can switch out `all` with `any` and do

```
Filter(
    function(x) case_when(
        all(is.na(x)) ~ FALSE,
        !any(is.na(x)) & var(x, na.rm = TRUE) == 0 ~ FALSE,
        TRUE ~ TRUE
    ), 
    df
)
#   a  b  c
# 1 1 NA  1
# 2 2  1  2
# 3 3  1 NA
# 4 4  1  3
# 5 5  1  4
```